# How to host my local Application and local database together in Azure?

Tags: hosting, azure-web-app-service

I have application build in Visual studio 2015 and local sql server 2015 , which application presently using local server. I need my application to host in azure with same database .

Comment: ok ,, ? 1st, this isn't a question .. 2nd, this is the wrong place to ask about which software to use ...  Server Fault might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How to host my local Application and local database together in Azure?

According to your description, I suggest you could create azure web apps to host your web application and create a [azure sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview) to store your data.

Besides, if you want your web application still use the local host sql, you need to use [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview) to connect to on-premises SQL Server(your local sql server).

More details, you could refer to below article:
[Connect to on-premises SQL Server from a web app in Azure App Service using Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server)

If you want to manage your own application and sql server, you could also consider using [azure VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/). By using this, you could install an IIS to host your web application and SQL server to store your data.